# listeners inside arrayAdapter getView method

Tags: android, listview, listener

I have a custom row_item for ListViews with an image, a pair of TextViews and a checkBox. 
From what I have understood, as checkBox is a focusable element it steals the focus from the listView so the OnListItemClicked is never fired unless I set every row_item as not clickable and I block descendants focusability.

Then for managing the checkBoxes changes I set in my adapter getView method an "OnCheckedChangeListener" for my checkBoxes.

Is this a bad way of doing this? (Because I am creating new Listeners every time getView is called)
Is there an other way of doing the same?

I attach some code so it's easier to understand what I mean.

getView method: (inside arrayAdapter)

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    /** recycling views */
    View row = convertView;
    PregoHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new PregoHolder();
        holder.imgIcon = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
        holder.txtNews = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.txtNews);
        holder.chBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (PregoHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    Prego Prego = data[position];
    holder.txtTitle.setText(Prego.title);
    holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(Prego.icon);
    holder.txtNews.setText(Prego.news);
    holder.chBox.setChecked(Prego.checked);

    /** wiring up Listeners... 
     * (works fine but we are creating new listener each time)
     * (Done like this because of the custom list view focusable issue)
     */

    holder.chBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean checked) {
            /** Getting the view position in the ListView */
            ListView parent = (ListView)(arg0.getParent()).getParent();
            int pos = parent.getPositionForView(arg0);

            if (checked){
                checkedPregons[pos] = true;
                pregonsChecked++;
            }
            else if (!checked){
                checkedPregons[pos] = false;
                pregonsChecked--;
            }

            Toast.makeText(context, pregonsChecked+" is/are checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    row.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //mMode = ((Activity)context).startActionMode(new PregonsActionModes());
            ListView parent = (ListView)v.getParent();
            int pos = parent.getPositionForView(v);
            Toast.makeText(context, "getView should show prego "+pos,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    return row;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need to make other elements of the listview clickable? Can you drill down? If both of those are negatives, then it might be better to toggle the checked state on row click.

Comment: I need to make the list item clickable so when you press outside the checkbox but inside one row it opens another activity.
I also tried to manage this with the row click but then when I only press inside the checkbox no listener is fired.
(So I had to first toggle the state of the checkbox and then click the row...)
Thats why I decided to do it like this...

Answer (score 3):

i suppose there could be a better way to go about it, but this isn't something i'd lose sleep over. Your method is wildly implemented by many android developers new and old and it's just a plain natural way to go about it. Moreover, keep in mind that the `ListView` only has as many rows as you can see on the screen at one time (and constantly is calling `getView` when you scroll), so you're talking about 8 - 12 made objects at any given time (obviously totally guessing), so your bottle-neck won't be here. In fact, depending on where the objects that I need to modify are, i don't even think about it.

**But** using `OnCheckedChangeListener` in a `ListView` is something i'd heavily warn against. like i said, `getView` is called for every row as it's being scrolled and made. This checked changed listener is being fired just as it's being made and notwithstanding there's absolutely no guarantees that `getView` is being called just *once* for each row, in fact i guarantee otherwise. Thus those code blocks are probably getting fired up the wazoo, even though you probably only intended for if the `CheckBox` box tick was handled manually. Put a relatively more intensive command like `notifyDataSetChanged()` and you'll see your `ListView` lock up from this phenomenom.

The solution is to simply use a checkbox `onClickListener` instead and check for `isChecked()` inside.

Comment: Great!! Thanks for your answer! I thought that in the worst case it would only be a couple of objects made at a time as you said but I was worried about if I was doing something else wrong that I didn't even thought. (like the onCheckedChangeListener)

Thanks again!