# ListView crashes, can't handle holder class

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Hello StackOverflowers,

after years and months and weeks of lurking I've finally encounterd a problem which neither the android developer site nor existing posts could solve, so please if possible assist me on this little problem.

What do I want to achieve with my code? (updated!)
→ I want to create a list, with CheckBoxes, after choosing a few of them I want to transfer the checked ones into the next Activity.
The following piece of code will not tackle the problem regarding the passing on. All I want to achieve with the 2 classes provided is, that I can check Items scroll up and down and that they remember if they were checked.

My Problem (updated!)
→ The CheckBoxes in the ListView do not remember if they were checked after scrolling back to their position.

I've encapsuled the problematic code into this separate Project

Here is the Code.
Note that the Planet-class and the PlanetAdapter are in the same JavaClass.

-----------> MainAcitivty<----------------------

```
package com.example.christian.listviewwithcheckboxes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
                checkbox.setChecked(!checkbox.isChecked());

                Planet p = planetList.get(position);
                p.setSelected(checkbox.isChecked());
                plAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checkbox checked/unchecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayPlanetList() {
        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();

        planetList.add((new Planet("please ", 29)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("help ", 30)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("me", 31)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("earth", 1)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("moon", 2)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("mercury", 3)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("jupiter", 4)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("venus", 5)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("pluto", 6)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("mars", 7)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("KOI-1843.03", 8)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("KOI-1843.01", 9)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("KOI-1843.02", 10)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-9b", 11)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-9c", 12)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-9d", 13)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("GJ 160.2b", 14)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 240210b", 15)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("OGLE-05-309L b", 16)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("WASP-82 b", 17)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Gliese 1214b", 18)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-153b", 19)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-153c", 20)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 4203 b", 21)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 4203 c", 22)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 179079 b", 23)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 187123 b", 24)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 187123 c", 25)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-431 b", 26)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-431 b", 27)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-431 d", 28)));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, this);
        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);
    }
}
```

-----------> MainAcitivty<----------------------

-----------> PlanetAdapter<----------------------

```
package com.example.christian.listviewwithcheckboxes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

class Planet {
    String name;
    int distance;
    boolean selected = false;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getDistance() {
        return distance;
    }

    public void setDistance(int distance) {
        this.distance = distance;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    public Planet(String name, int distance) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.distance = distance;
    }

}

public class PlanetAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Planet> {

    private List<Planet> planetList;
    private Context context;


    public PlanetAdapter(List<Planet> planetList, Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.single_listview_item, planetList);
        this.planetList = planetList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    private static class PlanetHolder {
        public TextView planetName;
        public TextView distView;
        public CheckBox chkBox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        PlanetHolder holder = new PlanetHolder();

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService((Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_listview_item, null);

            holder.planetName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.distView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            holder.chkBox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);

            v.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        Planet p = planetList.get(position);
        holder.planetName.setText((p.getName()));
        holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
        holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());

        holder.chkBox.setTag(p);

        return v;
    }
}
```

-----------> PlanetAdapter<----------------------

StackOverflow-Team to the rescue please :)

Sincerely 
Chris

edit (updated): no errors occure at this point, however the checkBoxes remember not if they were checked while scrolling up and down.

PS: Thank you for your help, you are helping me out tremendously, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an answer with a colleague of mine.

http://www.lalit3686.blogspot.in/2012/06/today-i-am-going-to-show-how-to-deal.html

This is a pretty neat project to show you how you should set up a ListView with Checkboxes.

Thanks for your hard work everybody, speacial thanks @RediOne1.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

You should replace the `holder.chkBox.setTag(p);` with `v.setTag(p)`. At this point, the `else` statement will always set the holder to `null`.

Comment: tired it, the app crashes as soon as I start scrolling, however the error occures now here

 } else {
            holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();
        }

Answer (score 0):

I've updated my answer, due to our conversation in comments.
I hope, it'll work :-) I didn't test it.

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<Planet> planetList;
    PlanetAdapter plAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        displayPlanetList();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.chk_box);
                checkbox.setChecked(!checkbox.isChecked());

                Planet p = planetList.get(position);
                p.setSelected(checkbox.isChecked());
                plAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked, state is " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void displayPlanetList() {
        planetList = new ArrayList<Planet>();
        planetList.add((new Planet("please ", 29)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("help ", 30)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("me", 31)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("earth", 1)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("moon", 2)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("mercury", 3)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("jupiter", 4)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("venus", 5)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("pluto", 6)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("mars", 7)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("KOI-1843.03", 8)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("KOI-1843.01", 9)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("KOI-1843.02", 10)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-9b", 11)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-9c", 12)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-9d", 13)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("GJ 160.2b", 14)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 240210b", 15)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("OGLE-05-309L b", 16)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("WASP-82 b", 17)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Gliese 1214b", 18)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-153b", 19)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-153c", 20)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 4203 b", 21)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 4203 c", 22)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 179079 b", 23)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 187123 b", 24)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("HD 187123 c", 25)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-431 b", 26)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-431 b", 27)));
        planetList.add((new Planet("Kepler-431 d", 28)));

        plAdapter = new PlanetAdapter(planetList, this);
        // ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lv.setAdapter(plAdapter);


    }
}
```

in your Adapter you can remove this line:

### PlanetAdapter

```
 holder.chkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((MainActivity) context);
```

Comment: This only solves a part of the problem, now I can scroll freely but as soon as I check a checkBox and scroll the app crashes again.


edit: the errors occure now in the adapterClass in line
`holder.chkBox.setChecked(p.isSelected());`

and in the mainclass in line
`int pos = lv.getPositionForView(buttonView);`

Comment: Please update your java code in question. Or paste link to pastebin with your current code

Comment: updated everything, thank you very much for your help, I'm really lost at this point. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe this topic will be helpful for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14083523/listeners-inside-arrayadapter-getview-method

I would try to delete `setOnCheckedChangeListener` in your adapter, and then add `onItemClickListener` to your listview. `onItemClickListener` will return you clicked `view`, then in this view, you can find checkbox, and check if it's checked?

Comment: I tried to follow your lead but got stuck, could you please elaborate with a couple lines of code?

Comment: The answer worked partially, I now can check the boxes and scroll down, however when I scroll back the checkBox is unchecked again and the Toast.make part is not reached.
I'll update my code now